# How to return an element of a tag in beautiful soup?

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

Really basic question:

How would.I return 001, 002...101 from:

```
<us-applicant sequence="001" app-type="applicant" designation="us-only">
...
<us-applicant sequence="101" app-type="applicant" designation="us-only">
```

Using beautiful soup?  I know the basic look for returning something between two tags, but I'm not sure what this element actually is

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this, using list comprehension, you get the attribute using `['sequence']`:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

data = '''
<us-applicant sequence="001" app-type="applicant" designation="us-only">
<us-applicant sequence="100" app-type="applicant" designation="us-only">
<us-applicant sequence="101" app-type="applicant" designation="us-only">
'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'html.parser')
>>> [tag['sequence'] for tag in soup.findAll('us-applicant')]
['001', '100', '101']
```